# C# Adding a Datatable to a Datatable

Tags: c#

I know that sounds really weird, but I am fairly new to C# and I am hoping you guys can help me out.

I am looping thru a DataTable, then excute a qry and get the the result into a DataTable.

Works OK for one record, but as soon as there are more records, only the last record is in the DT, which makes sense, I just do not know how to fix it. I need to have all the records in the DT.

Here is my code, any suggestions are welcome....

> ```
>     DataTable dt = ml.getRegistration();
>     DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
>
>     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
>     {     
>         dt2 = ml.getRegistrationExport(row["ID"]);
>
>     }
>     GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
>     GridView1.DataBind();
> ```

Comment: What does `getRegistrationExport` do?  Add the code for it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you need to do with the data? Do you have control over the code for `ml.GetRegistration()`?

Comment: If it's "resolved" then vote up the right response and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Could someone please edit "thru" to say "through"?  With help, we can eliminate that word from this horribly lazy culture!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ml.getRegistrationExport is returning a datatable, then it overwrites the data as you loop through the first datatable..  You need to use dt2.merge to add all the data to the datatable.  HTH.

```
DataTable dt = ml.getRegistration();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{

dt2.merge(ml.getRegistrationExport(row["ID"]));

}

GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you would not do justice to the super fast and helpful reply. I am speechless. 

But that's all I have right now, a big THANK YOU, it works great!! 

Steve

Comment: No problem, glad to be of service.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems I see is each row you are looping through you are replace dt2.  So if you have 5 rows, you will replace dt2 5 times and which ever row happen to be last would rule dt2.

I would re think this.

Are what you are trying to do is add a row to dt2 for each row in the original dt?

```
DataTable dt = ml.getRegistration();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = dt2.NewRow();

    // What Does getRegistrationExport return?  
    // A row or series of rows or a new DT?  
    // Each would change solution
    newRow["SomeColumn"] = ml.getRegistrationExport(row["ID"]);

    dt2.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I doubt it is the row, because you wouldn't be able to assign it to dt2.