# Retriving Values from a datable to another datatable using C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two DataTable [System.Data] .One contains three rows id,name,date and another contains id only>How can I get the value [id] of first datatable to second one.Is there any possible way to achieve this without using iteration methods. I have values in the first datatable. I need to copy it to another one.I don't wan't to execute any query in between.This is not what i required [C# Adding a Datatable to a Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917999/c-adding-a-datatable-to-a-datatable)

Comment: Do you mean that one (DataTable1) contains 3 COLUMNS (id,name,date)? Also, are you hoping to copy all the IDs from DataTable1 into DataTable2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method:

```
        string[] columnsToCopy = { "id" };
        DataTable tableNew = dtSource.DefaultView.ToTable("NameOfTableToCreate", false, columnsToCopy);
```

Answer (score 0):

For copying all the data and structure you can use the `DataTable.Copy()`

[DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx)

Comment: @Hps
: it will copy all columns.but the question with copy only one column.

Comment: I just want only one value. Not all values

Comment: Vyas is correct. If performance is not a constraint, then you can delete the other two columns after copying. table.Columns.Remove("columnName");

Comment: @Harie:Please check my other answer below.